# Reset/Clear selected slicers in Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have 6 slicers/filter on a Power BI report page ( 5 dropdowns and 1 date slicer).
There is a clear all slicer button that resets the all dropdowns and date slicer.
Is there anyway, when the clear all slicer button is clicked, all the filters are reset except the date slicer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can utilize Bookmarks for this.

1. Go to View > select Bookmarks
2. The Bookmarks pane will show up next to Filters. In it, click 'Add' and name your bookmark (ex 'Summary page- Clear filters')
3. In your page, situate your data exactly how you want it to be when someone hits the Clear button: Clear all filters except for your Date slicer, expand/collapse visuals, etc)
4. Insert a button (I usually use the arrow that curves up and backward. In the formatting pane for the shape, I add the word 'Clear').
5. In the formatting pane for the button, go to Action. Type: Bookmark, Bookmark: 'WhateverYouNamedIt'

Now when you click your button in the page, it will clear all the filters except the Date.

Anytime you make updates to your page, go ahead and right click on your bookmark and select 'Update'.

Comment: when reviewing a report in Power BI service, is it possible that when a user clears all filters, the date slicer remains unaffected? For example, if a user selected a date range, cleared all filters, the selected date range remains the same (that the user had selected before clearing all filters)?

Answer (score 0):

In March 2023, Power bi added a button for that. You can find that under the insert tab- > buttons
Power BI March 2023 Apply all Slicer, Clear All Slicer Buttons:  https://youtu.be/tfQT31AZEoY

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply.
Here is the scenerio.
In Power BI desktop, i have saved a bookmark where date slicer is set to show between 1 April 2023 to 10 April 2023.

Once the report is published, a user is using the report and he sets date on the slicer to April 10, 2023 - April 13, 2023.

When reset/clear slicer button is pressed, the date slicer sets back to bookmark value. So is there anyway the date slicer can maintain it's selected date range to user selected instead of bookmark value.

Thanks